# Problem 17 from Herstein's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

This is a problem from Herstein's book about $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Prove that $n$ is a prime number if and only if in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $[a][b]=[0]$ implies that $[a]=[b]=[0]$.

**Proof:**

I. Let in $\mathbb{Z}_n\ [a][b]=[0]$ implies that $[a]=[b]=[0]$ but $n$ is composite. Then $n=st$ where $1<s,\ t<n$. Then $[0]=[n]=[st]=[s][t]$ so $[s]=[t]=[0]$. Since $[s]=[0]$ it means that $n\mid s$ but this is contradiction since $1<s<n$. So we get our desired proposition.

II. $n\in \mathbb{P}$ then $[a][b]=[0]$ implies that $[a]=[b]=[0]$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_n$).

Suppose by contradiction: $n\in \mathbb{P}$ but $[a][b]=[0]$ implies that for some $a,\ b$ we have $[a]\neq [0]$$[b]\neq[0]$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_n$) (the case when exactly one of the $[a]$ and $[b]$ nonzero in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is impossible).

From $[a][b]=[0]$ we have $n\mid ab$ and since $n$ is prime then WLOG $n\mid a$ which meeans that $[a]=[0]$ which is impossible since $[a]\neq [0]$.

What do you think about that proof?

Comment: Seems okay to me!

Comment: You mean "$[a][b]=0$ implies $[a]=0$ or $[b]=0$".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, no! without "or".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I.H.Herstein in his book indeed wrote "$[a]=[b]=0$. I think it does not mean that $[a]=0$ or $[b]=0$

Comment: Then this is a typo in the book. Clearly $[a]=[b]=0$ is not a valid conclusion. For example, take $p=3$, $a=3$, $b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of I is essentially good, but contradiction is not necessary.

Suppose $n$ is composite, so $n=st$ with $1<s,t<n$. Then $[s][t]=[n]=[0]$, but $[s]\ne[0]$ and $[t]\ne[0]$.

Your attempt at II is defective, I'm afraid. The hypothesis by contradiction would be “$n$ is prime and *there exist* $[a]\ne[0]$ and $[b]\ne[0]$ with $[a][b]=[0]$”.

Again, the idea is right, but no contradiction is necessary.

Suppose $n$ is prime and $[a][b]=[0]$, so $n\mid ab$. Since $n$ is prime, we get that either $n\mid a$ or $n\mid b$. Hence $[a]=[0]$ or $[b]=[0]$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to write "there exist". I meant that but I forgot. Sorry

Comment: Why Herstein wrote $[a]=[b]=0$ but you have derived $[a]=0$ OR $[b]=0$.

Comment: @RFZ One cannot derive $[a]=[b]=[0]$; think to $a=0$ and $b=1$